# Document.form.submit() not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name='form' id='form'>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center"  style="BORDER-RIGHT: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #fe03b4 1px solid">
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 3px">
                <b><font color="#f803f8" size="1">Eyes</font></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select size="1" name="eyes" class="input" id="eyes" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f7ed79; COLOR: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; width:150px;">`
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="1"<? if ($eyes=="1") echo "selected"; ?>>Blue</option>
                    <option value="2"<? if ($eyes=="2") echo "selected"; ?>>Green</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center"  style="BORDER-RIGHT: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #fe03b4 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #fe03b4 1px solid">
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 3px">
                <b><font color="#f803f8" size="1">Description</font></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows='5' name='description'  cols='120'><? echo "$description"; ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br />

    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td  align="center">
                <input name='Update' type='submit' onClick="if(document.form.eyes.value == ''){ alert('Eyes Color?'); document.form.eyes.focus(); return false; } else 
                if(document.form.description.value==''){ alert('Description?'); document.form.description.focus(); return false; } else
                { document.form.submit(); parent.scrollTo(0,0); }" value='Update' style="width:100%; font-size:10px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The first alert (eyes) works, but the second does not give me the alert, and it saves even if no text is inserted.

The EYES column in data base is defined as 0, then I can do an UPDATE selecting the option 1 or 2.

Can the text field in the database be updated if there has been no previous save? In another words, the text column in the database is NULL (no text saved), and I attempt to do an UPDATE without a SAVE.

Any help here?

Comment: Some code formatting please..

Comment: MY EYES! Please format your code or post only the relevant parts.

Comment: no body is gonna help seeing this type of code here.please format with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because, the type of button is submit. if you want to control submit manually change it to button. Or use form submit event instead, validate the form in the submit event and cancel submition if it is not valid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536972(v=vs.85).aspx